# How to display a boxplot with a missing y-axis range using gap.boxplot (base r)? (almost there, struggling with an error)

Tags: r, boxplot, plotrix

I want to create a nice boxplot with this dataset:

```
data_N3_minmax = structure(c(2.71177214885543, 4.36849175181861, 17.626304994383, 
17.7213767231357, 1116.19429181322, 1121.5558117271, NA, NA, 
5.54438655223586, 15.5774104850416, 7.34658260987168, 25.2590667564114, 
8.44869502735733, 17.5713360077048), .Dim = c(2L, 7L))
```

I first used this code:

```
label=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7")

boxplot(data_N3_minmax, xlab="", ylab="", names=label)
```

This code produces this graph:
[image]

You see that there is a huge difference between V3 and the rest. Therefore, I wanted to incorporate an y-axis gap.
I started with the gap.boxplot function from the package plotrix. However, I ran into a problem that I don't know how to fix.
I used this code:

```
library("plotrix")

label=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7")

gap.boxplot(data_N3_minmax, gap=list(top=c(30,1000), bottom=c(NA,NA)), xlab="", ylab="", names=label)
```

I only want to get one gap between the values of V3 and the other boxplots, so I do not use the bottom gap.
Sadly, I got this error message:
*Error in gap.boxplot(data_N3_minmax, gap = list(top = c(50, 1000), bottom = c(NA,  :
gap cannot include the median, interquartiles or the staples*.

This confuses me because the gap I want to include (between 30 and 1000) does not include the median, interquartiles or the staples. Can anyone help me to solve this problem or show me how I can incorporate an axis gap in another way? I mostly have experience with base R plotting and no experience with ggplot, so I would prefer to do this in base R.

Comment: Did you check with `boxplot(data_N3_minmax)$stats` whether indeed neither of the boxplots, staples/whiskers included, reaches into the specified gap? (Aside: are you calculating boxplot stats from the two extremes of each sample rather than from the sample itself?)

Comment: @I_O yes I checked and they do not reach into the specified gap. I also tried to make the gap way smaller but that also did not work. Yes, I am using only the two extremes of my sample and manually adding the data points within the box, as I did not need whiskers and only a bar for what I am trying to visualise.

Comment: Strange. Please add the output of `dput(data_N3_minmax)` to your question to help others reproduce and hopefully resolve the error (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As to the other issue: although R will produce a boxplot for two values, constructing it from the extremes of a sample will be highly misleading about the sample distribution (unless you have a large sample from a symmetric distribution).

Comment: The data of data_N3_minmax is visible at the top of the post. Or do I need to include it in a different way than a picture?

Comment: While the data is visible, people volunteering to help might be less volunteering to type the data off a screenshot to be able tho help. How and why is right there in my comment ;-) Aside: to just omit whiskers and staples from a boxplot, do: ` boxplot(..., whisklty = 0, staplelty = 0)` (see `?boxplot`). To see how misleading a boxplot from the sample's extremes can get, try `x <- rbeta(100, .1, .9); boxplot(x, range(x))`.

Comment: Thank you for making my post more clear, I have edited it now. Yes I would also normally include the whiskers, but this data set origanally only has 4 data points per plot anyway and it shows averages per year for 4 years. The extra data points I add manually to the boxplot as extra lines instead of whiskers and I add a median to the boxplot as well. It shows exactly the same with whiskers, but just works better with how I want to visualise the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255158/discussion-between-i-o-and-laura).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the all-NA column no. 4 which raises the error. Leaving it out will work:

```
    gap.boxplot(data_N3_minmax[, -4],
                gap=list(top=c(30,1000), bottom=c(NA,NA)) #, ...
                )
```

[image: omit all-NA variables saves gap boxplot]

**edit**

sort of hackish solution to keep an empty seat for variable no. 4:

- replace `NA`s with zero
- set border color of box no. 4 zo `NA`:

```
    data_N3_minmax[,4] <- 0

    gap.boxplot(data_N3_minmax,
                border = c(rep(TRUE,3), NA, rep(TRUE, 3)),
                gap = list(top=c(30,1000), bottom=c(NA,NA))
                )
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to leave the space for column 4? I want to keep the x-axis the same as before, as my other graphs that don't need a gap do have values for that column and I want to keep it consistent.

Comment: It works now well but I have 2 additional questions. 1) How do I add tick marks and values on the top part of the y-axis, above the gap? 2) I added some visual edits to the code: `label=c("Control", 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

gap.boxplot(data_N3_minmax, 
            col='#238b45', names=label,  cex.axis=2.8, family="Times", lwd=8, 
            whisklty = 0, staplelty = 0, medcol="#238b45", xlab="", ylab="",
            border = c(rep(TRUE,3), NA, rep(TRUE, 3)),
            gap = list(top=c(30,1110), bottom=c(NA,NA)) )` but the labels of the x-axis, lwd and cex.axis are not plotted. Any idea why?